# Where can I put my MFC Control initialization code

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc, custom-controls

I'm writing an MFC CEdit derived control, and I need to add initialization code once the control's m_hwnd is filled.

Which function can I override or which message can I handle to achieve this?

I tried with OnCreate, but It seems to work only for dialogs

EDIT:
The thing I'm initializing is the edit's cue banner

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following Mark Ransom's hint, I finally found a better function to implement my intitialization. While overloading CWnd::SubclassWindow is a good idea, this function is not virtual and it would require a call from the subclass pointer. Calling SubclassWindow from a CWnd* would not work.

I found the function [CWnd::PreSubclassWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d463726%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). It's virtual and is called just before SubclassWindow. Since m_hwnd is valid there, it is a good place to write the code I need.
In addition, the function is virtual and is called automatically by the framework so I don't need to worry about having the good pointer type

Answer (score 5):

OnCreate doesn't work if the control is on a dialog, because the control is created before it can be subclassed to your window class - that happens in the dialog's DoDataExchange.

You can override CWnd::SubclassWindow and call the base method before your own code.

Comment: SubclassWindow is not virtural, did you mean PreSubclassWindow?

Comment: @Goldorak84, it does not have to be virtual if you call the method on the object directly rather than from a base class pointer, as will be the case with MFC. Try it and see.

Comment: My object is dynamically subclassed with a CWnd* pointer, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Depending what exactly you are initializing, you can override `OnPaint()`, or you can add your initialization code into the `OnInitDialog()` in the Dialog class that the control is contained in.

Comment: I need to initialize the control's cue banner. 
OnPaint is not good for me as the initialization needs to be called only once. My control is a custom control, It will be used in over 200 dialogs, I wont put 200 times the initialization code in each dialog's OnInitDialog